# shared_ptr reset throws segmentation fault

Tags: c++11, segmentation-fault, shared-ptr

Tried this program out of curiosity to understand behavior of shared_ptr over raw pointers. I hope the problem could be double delete but here I am facing other:

```
MyClass *raw_ptr = new MyClass();
shared_ptr<MyClass> sptr1(raw_ptr);
shared_ptr<MyClass> sptr2 = sptr1;
cout << sptr1.use_count() << endl; // prints 2
sptr1.reset(); // occurs Segmentation Fault here
```

Expected Behavior: reduce the count to 1 and moves control to next line.

**Solved: Actual issue is at the next line in which sptr1 accessing the public class member MyClass::a which is invalid access after reset and hence the segfault. Confused because it didn't print the cout messages.**

```
cout << "count: "<< sptr1.use_count() 
     << "value: "<< sptr1->a;
```

Comment: Works for me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d0f9a81c10e187c

Comment: Are you sure the exception happens when you call `reset()`, or when the `sptr2` goes out of scope and the `MyClass` object is being deleted? The segmentation fault could occur in its destructor.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The error is in my code where I was calling the member of class using sptr1 immediately after reset which leads to segfault. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no issues in that code. It is perfectly fine.

So either your compiler is broken, your development environment is broken, or there's other code there you're not showing us which is responsible for the crash.

Comment: Actual error is in the next line of my code. I was trying to access MyClass member using sptr1 after reset. That is the reason for crash. Thanks.